# What does the += operator do within programming? (May be C# exclusive)

Tags: c#, operators

Well, the title pretty much says it all, I'm reading a beginner's book on C# programming, and in some of the example code, the author used the code:

```
dSum += students[i].dGPA;
```

(you only really need to focus on the +=)

So I asked my Computer Science teacher, and he recommended me to ask you guys...

P.S If you really need to know, this code snippet was used within a 'for' loop.

Comment: you need a smarter teacher

Comment: Functionally the same as `dSum = dSum + students[i].dGPA;`  And no, it's not c# exclusive, many languages use that construct.

Comment: When my teacher mentioned StackOverflow, he included a good warning.

Comment: A smarter teacher and a better book

Comment: Have your teacher post a question so I can vote it down.

Comment: Yeah, he doesn't know any C#, so that's why I think it might be C# exclusive... keep in mind he's only a high school teacher.

Comment: it is not a half bad question - the book ought to have explained it; but that the *teacher* did not have the answer is alarming.

Comment: Your teacher is terrible and lazy. Anywho, if you ever need a C# specific explanation just look on google for `MSDN Whatever you want` to get the documentation page... i.e `MSDN += operator` shows you a page for [C# operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) (which has a link for the [+= operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx))

Comment: @ForceBru generally teachers are not allowed to express some opinions about pupils... There is no such strict restriction on SO - like your suggestion about "get a better book" implies that OP did not put enough effort into finding an answer and may be consider offensive :)

Comment: FWIW, this exists in just about every language with basic syntax similar to C.

Comment: MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Comment: *Augmented/Compound assignment*  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment

Comment: @Luminous The fact that the OP was told to ask here doesn't make it an appropriate question for SO.  If you're voting up the question, instead of voting it down, you're just as bad as the teacher was for indicating that this question has any business whatsoever being asked here.

Comment: And now we created new and improved version "searched alot and found nothing.Help me ASPA" - "my teacher is .... and asked to post on SO"... It is really bad question for SO - basic search https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+operator+%2B%3D immediately gives one links to official documentation...

Comment: Next time I ask a question I'll definitely try and research a bit more beforehand, sorry :P

Comment: @Plutonix You're assuming the teacher didn't know the answer.  I assume he told the OP to go research the question himself and find his own answer, rather than spoon feeding him the answer to a question he ought to be able to find on his own.  He may in fact be a very good teacher.  Or he could be incompetent, we really can't say.

Answer (score 4):

```
dSum += students[i].dGPA;
```

is equivalent to

```
dSum = dSum + students[i].dGPA;
```

See Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Best to show at an example

```
int sum = 1;
sum += 1; //will result in 2.
```

same as

```
int sum = 1;
sum = sum + 1;
```

same goes if you want to concatenate a string:

```
string val = "some text";
val += " and some more"; // wil result in "Some text and some more".
```

Answer (score 1):

Would that not be explained in the book? Check the Index page for it.

it is a shorthand for `dSum = dSum + students[i].dGPA;`